# Show loading spinner before loading an page (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I have a page that takes to long to load ( I don't know why, maybe a question for another thread).
So I want to let the user know that the page is loading. But for some reason, I'm only able to make the spinner show indefinitely or not show at all. The page takes 10 seconds to load in debug mode.

```
 onPressed: () async {
                        showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    color: Colors.white),
                              );
                            });

                        await Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return FormIncident();
                        }));

                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      }
```

I also tried using showModal instead Navigator, and I still face the same problem

Comment: Some questions have to be answered first.

- Where are you fetching the data from? 
- Are you using a state management library like BloC?

Comment: Ok, you like to show a progressbar for 10 sec, and then navigate to new route?

Comment: No data to be fetched, just trying to load another page (Stateful Widget). No State management library

Comment: That cant be the case. If the page is slow on loading, that has to be because of data. You are telling me that both pages have no data and despite that, it takes like 10 secs to get loaded?

Comment: Yep, but im using a 32 dollars android phone to debug, and I'am using debug mode.

Comment: I just complied the appBundle, and its is actually blazing fast... but I still need to know how to make the spinner work

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing new page before data loading and your spinner doesn't showing. In your case, you need to add loader (spinner) to page where are you loading data. Without additional information I can't make example of your case, but if you are using `Future`, your `FormIncident` can be similar like this:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<TypeOfYourFuture>(
    future: yourFuture,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      // If your data is not loading show loader
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return LoaderWidget();
      // If your data is not loading show loader
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
         return ErrorWidget();
      }
      // In other cases you have a valid data and you can shot content
      return ContentWidget();
    }
  );
}
```

Add more info and we will try to find solution that specific to you.